# Induction proof of sum of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: proof-verification, induction, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci sequence is defined as follows:

$a_0=0,a_1=1,a_2=1$

$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2},n\geq 2$

And the problem asks:

Show, using induction:

$a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2=a_na_{n+1}$.

Here's my attempt:

Proof:

Let $P(n)$ be the statement $a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2=a_na_{n+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N} ,n\geq 2$.

Base case:

Let $n=2$, then $1^2+1^2=1*2\implies 2=2$. Therefore, $P(2)$ is true.

Inductive assumption:

Let $n\in \mathbb{N} ,n\geq 2$ be generic, and assume that $P(n)$ is true, i.e. $a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2=a_na_{n+1}$.

Induction step:

$(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)+a_{n+1}^2=a_na_{n+1}+a_{n+1}^2=a_{n+1}(a_n+a_{n+1})=a_{n+1}a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}a_{(n+1)+1}$. Therefore, $P(n+1)$ is true. $\blacksquare$

I'm not sure why $n\in \mathbb{N}$ isn't in the question, but I assumed that. How is my proof? Did I miss anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Your proof is quite fine.

Comment: Very nice, correct proof. +1

Comment: You have implicitly used that $n\in\Bbb N$. Expressions like $a_n$ or $P(n)$ are not defined otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You have proven that:

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N} ,n\geq 2 : P(n)$$

But assuming we define $P(n)$ as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i^2 = a_n a_{n+1}$$

You'll find that $P(n)$ also holds for $n=0$ and $n=1$, i.e. you can prove:

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: P(n)$$

... and it certainly *looks* like that's what you are supposed to prove.

So, that means that you will need $n=0$ as your base case, and not $n=2$

P.s. [The Wikipedia page on Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) has a nice 'proof' by picture of the theorem you're proving:

[image]

[image]